# Prove Is a Filled Magic Square

Tags: magic-square

Can someone prove that if $S$ is a filled magic square, and $T$ is obtained from $S$ by switching two rows or two columns, then $T$ is also a filled magic square.

So an example that I came up with was: [image]   and [image]  are magic squares related by the exchange of the first two columns.

Comment: You examples are no magic squares. The diagonal sums are not equal. Remember that a magic square needs to have constant row, column _and_ diagonal sum.

Comment: @AlexR Diagonals don't have to be equal

Comment: They do [cf. wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square). If they didn't, your proposition would be outright trivial, though.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by outright trivial

Comment: Addition is commutative. The swap operation only swaps two summands in each row / column depending on whether you swap columns / rows resp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we switch two columns. Clearly, the column sums are unchanged by this operation.  If they were all equal before the switch, they are still equal because the columns themselves are exactly the same.

In each row, the column switch operation leaves all the numbers the same; all it does is reorder the numbers by switching positions of two of the numbers in the row.  Since addition is commutative, the row sum is unchanged.

The same argument shows that switching rows does not change the row or column sums.

However, the argument does *not* show that the diagonal sums are unchanged, and  it cannot, because your example shows that they can change.

Comment: So if we disregard the diagonals, then the first three paragraphs are sufficient?

Comment: Sufficient for what?

Comment: Sufficient proof